# Error received: "unable to resolve root". How to grant access to watchman?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, watchman

I installed a react-native starter project and when running, it asked to grant permission to watchman to access my system's files. I naively declined, but now I get the following error whenever trying to run the folder:

```
Error: unable to resolve root /Users/ckoong/Desktop/Repos/rn-starter: failed to opendir(/Users/ckoong/Desktop/Repos/rn-starter): Operation not permitted
    at BunserBuf.<anonymous> (/Users/ckoong/Desktop/Repos/rn-starter/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:95:23)
    at BunserBuf.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at BunserBuf.process (/Users/ckoong/Desktop/Repos/rn-starter/node_modules/bser/index.js:292:10)
    at /Users/ckoong/Desktop/Repos/rn-starter/node_modules/bser/index.js:247:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
Emitted 'error' event on WatchmanWatcher instance at:
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/ckoong/Desktop/Repos/rn-starter/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/lib/WatchmanWatcher.js:130:10)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at BunserBuf.<anonymous> (/Users/ckoong/Desktop/Repos/rn-starter/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:107:12)
    at BunserBuf.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at /Users/ckoong/Desktop/Repos/rn-starter/node_modules/bser/index.js:249:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
  watchmanResponse: {
    version: '4.7.0',
    error: 'unable to resolve root /Users/ckoong/Desktop/Repos/rn-starter: failed to opendir(/Users/ckoong/Desktop/Repos/rn-starter): Operation not permitted'
```

I've seen various people saying to grant access to watchman in system preferences, however, when searching in the window, I'm not seeing any reference to watchman anywhere on my system.

I'm working on Big Sur.

Please assist.

Comment: I personally did not encounter this issue, but I read about it here and maybe it is useful (long story short: remove watchman and install it again) https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2941#issuecomment-142710132

Comment: Are you using MacOS?

Comment: in a shell try to grant 777 permissions with this command "sudo chmod 777 -R /Users/ckoong/Desktop/Repos/rn-starter" (777 no es the best option but could help you...)

Answer (score 5):

adding a `.watchmanconfig` file in the root and putting a `{}` inside it has worked for me

Answer (score 3):

As with @Fraser's answer  You must grant Full Disk Access to watchman. Go to `System Preferences` -> `Security & Privacy` -> `Privacy tab` -> scroll down and click `Full Disk Access` Check off

- Terminal
- sh or Watchman (Mine showed only sh)

Then run `watchman watch <dir>` and start the app

Answer (score 2):

Go to `System Preferences` -> `Security & Privacy` -> `Privacy tab` -> scroll down and click `Full Disk Access`, and then check `Watchman`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the project in the `~/Documents` folder. I moved it elsewhere and it worked. I think the same issue applies to `~/Desktop` folder.
[source](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/977#issuecomment-980445494)